# Unable to get location using LocationRequest or getLastLocation()

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I've been working on this for quite some time. I've tried everything I can think of.

I'm trying to get a rough location (Coarse location). First try was the following:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

googleApiClient.connect();
```

And then this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    lastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

    if(lastKnownLocation == null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
    else
    {
        moveMap();
    }
}
```

This returns null. Totally possible, no worries. However, after this, I tried to request location updates using LocationRequest, as follows:

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
```

And then this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    lastKnownLocation = location;
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    moveMap();
}
```

Both of these methods don't give me any sort of a location. That's possible as well, so I downloaded a Fake GPS app, set Location Mode to GPS Only in phone settings, and set a fake location.

When I run my app after doing this, it still fails to find a location. I've also tried with:

```
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
```

Nothing seems to work. Permissions are in the manifest. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237729/how-to-get-initial-location-with-locationmanager/30237809#30237809

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078924/locationmanager-is-sending-last-location-all-time/24239747#24239747

Comment: That's not the recommended way to get location anymore. There are newer APIs available that are being used above.

Comment: where you are requesting for location updates?

Comment: But what if I need a not-so-accurate location quickly? Point is, if I open Google maps app right now, it will show me my location. Where does it get that from?

Comment: @Nag Check the code now (onConnected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing the following:

Removed this:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();

googleApiClient.connect();
```

Added this:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
```

And moved the **connect()** call to onStart().

I assume the problem was the absence of **addConnectionCallbacks**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this to start getting location updates ?

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( 
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049388/3728591).

Comment: Yeah I just added the code to my question. It was already in my code but I hadn't pasted it here.

Comment: please check link given in my ans. That answer code is in working condition.